# 'how to escape colon in {xlink:href}'.format_map(attributes)?

Tags: python-3.x, escaping

**Summary:** The `'{key:spec}'.format_map(dic)` allows to format the value from the `dic` accessed by the `key`. The `spec` says how it should be formatted. However, what if I want the separating colon be the part of the key? How should I tell that the colon is not a separator and the next characters are not a specification?

**Details:** I use string templates for transforming XML attributes to another text. Say, I have attributes of an XML element in the `attributes` dictionary. One of them has the key `'xlink:href'` (literal name of the attribute). When using `.format_map()` method, how the format string should be written?

The `'{xlink:href}'.format_map(attributes)` does not work. Python complains `KeyError: 'xlink'`. (The `href` would probably be considered a bad specification, but the exception stops further processing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to escape colon in `{xlink:href}`.
[You can't specify arbitrary keys in the replacement field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
attribute_name    ::=  identifier
element_index     ::=  integer | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
conversion        ::=  "r" | "s" | "a"
format_spec       ::=  <described in the next section>
```

Comment: Thanks, J.F. ! I was not sure if I did not overlook something. I have worked around the problem. ;)